# Partial delete success: expected behavior? workarounds?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm connecting to Google Cloud SQL from AppEngine and I'm running into issues with large batch deletes that seem to succeed partially. I have three related tables - A stores child objects of B, B stores child objects of C. Let's call them Pets, People, and Cities - each person tends to have around one pet, but might have several or might have none. Each city has a lot of people.  I'm working on scaling up to larger cities - I'd like to get to millions eventually. Things worked fine up to around 1000 people, but when I got to around 5000 people, I got some weird behavior on deletion.

This is what I do when I delete a city:

My pets refer to my people by foreign key ID, so I have to remove the pets first. My query looks like:

```
DELETE FROM Pets WHERE person_id IN (SELECT person_id FROM People WHERE city_id=?)
```

Code looks like:

`PreparedStatement stat = connection.prepareStatement(<above statement>);
 stat.setString(1, city_id);
 return stat.executeUpdate();`

Then if that succeeds (returns > 0 is the condition I'm using), I delete all the people (the people refer to city by foreign key ID) with a query like:

```
DELETE FROM People WHERE city_id=?
```

and similar code to the pets.

This is where it gets weird. My deletion of pets returns only ~2000 (one time it was 1405, another time 2803) out of the expected 5000 deletions. I don't get an exception or anything. The other ~3000 pets are still in the database - I can go inspect it manually and see them:

`MySQL [adam1]> select count(*) from People ppl inner join Pets pts on ppl.person_id=pts.person_id where ppl.city="some city id here";
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 2197 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.16 sec)`

Then of course my deletion of people fails because of a foreign key constraint violation. I don't see anything strange about my database at these points - CPU utilization hasn't ever gone over 70%, memory utilization is pretty low, no updates happening simultaneously. I do see tons and tons of messages like "Aborted connection  to db: '' user: '' host: 'cloudsqlproxy~' (Got an error reading communication packets)", but those happen all the time (many per second, when the db is heavily in use), don't seem to be correlated with this issue.

Is this expected, that a delete partially succeeds? Is there a way for me to detect that it has only partially succeeded besides trying and failing to delete the referenced people?

The project ID is adam-dev-193118, database adam1. The pet, people, and city tables are Runs, Batches, and Projects. Example log is at 2018-02-07 17:43:16.107 EST. Happy to provide additional information.

*Edit: my original query started taking a very long time. I swear it didn't always do that, but I can't prove it. In any case, I switched to a join instead of a subselect (which now takes ~1s instead of ~45s), and I still have exactly the same problem. Query is now like:

```
DELETE a FROM People b INNER JOIN Pets a ON a.person_id=b.person_id WHERE b.city_id=?;
```

Comment: Have you checked after some time has passed?  There is an issue with consistency and db caching, where changes are not immediately visible.  But they "eventually" get changed.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering a similar thing, if maybe the call to executeUpdate was returning prematurely, maybe after some timeout, but the actual sql call continued to run in the background. But the number remaining in the database doesn't change over time and exactly matches the number not deleted by the call to executeUpdate (so when executeUpdate reported 2803 rows, there were 2197 left), so I ruled that out.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, it should have been obvious. Nothing is wrong with PreparedStatements or CloudSQL (as expected, of course). This is my own issue and has nothing to do with the "Aborted connection" errors.

For any who are interested, I hadn't realized that an asynchronously running part of my system is adding the Pets whenever someone is added to People. Adding People used to be so slow that adding Pets pretty much always kept up. Besides, usually you want the People to stick around for a while so you can do something with them, giving the Pets-adder even more time to catch up. I've been working on making People quicker to add, so it's become much faster and also I'm cycling through mass add-deletes to test this so people in People are very short-lived.

tl;dr: the Pets aren't deleted because they aren't there yet. However, because they're being added quickly, they are there by the time I manage to go double-check in the console.